# Puppeteer failed to render emojis when running in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, puppeteer, chromium

I have a script that uses puppeteer to take screenshot of DOM components and outputs an image. Everything works fine on MacOS but when I run this on Ubuntu the emojis become a rectangle. Does anyone know why is this happening?

- MacOS: (where you can see a rocket emoji)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeCEf.png]

- Ubuntu: (emoji becomes a rectangle)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1qyV.png]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiuple sources ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029661/18-04-color-emoji-not-showing-up-at-all-in-chrome-only-partially-in-firefox), [2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107835/emoji-support-for-chrome-on-linux), [3](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4086)) suggest using `fonts-noto-color-emoji` font to remedy this on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

**Update**: it is possible to do so starting with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ya I was looking at `fonts-noto-color-emoji` in ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I cannot find a way to install it. But after I switch to ubuntu 18.04 LTS then I can do `sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji` and then puppeteer renders the images fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using `chrome-aws-lambda` (i.e.: using a cloud function to execute Puppeteer), you can load the font right after instantiating the browser:

```js
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');

const browser = // ...
await chromium.font('https://raw.githack.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/master/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf');
```

However, note that the font is almost 10 MB. If instead of taking a screenshot you are generating a PDF, the output file size will increase significantly.